# Sort QTableView column containing index widgets

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I have a `QTableView` whose model is a `QStandardItemModel`. In one of the columns, I create new indexes and use `setIndexWidget` to assign them to a custom color-selection widget. I'd like to be able to sort the view using this column so users could group items with like colors. I've implemented the `operator<` for the custom widget, but whenever I try to use it I get a run-time debug assertion saying:

```
Expression: Invalid operator<
```

In order to sort by this column do I need to set some role data for the `QStandardItem` the widgets are attached to?

I think the operator< code is fine but I'm including it as well just in case.

```
bool operator<(const QPenWidget &rhs) const
{
    // use the RGB value to index the color
    int r_lhs, g_lhs, b_lhs, rgb_lhs;
    int r_rhs, g_rhs, b_rhs, rgb_rhs;

    this->m_pen.color().getRgb(&r_lhs, &g_lhs, &b_lhs);
    rgb_lhs = (r_lhs * 65536) + (g_lhs * 256) + b_lhs;

    rhs.m_pen.color().getRgb(&r_rhs, &g_rhs, &b_rhs);
    rgb_rhs = (r_rhs * 65536) + (g_rhs * 256) + b_rhs;

    if (rgb_lhs != rgb_rhs)
        return rgb_lhs < rgb_rhs;

    if (m_pen.style() != rhs.m_pen.style())
        return m_pen.style() < rhs.m_pen.style();

    return m_pen.width() < rhs.m_pen.width();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the `QStandardItemModel` uses whatever the data for the `Qt::DisplayRole` is to do the sorting. While it's possible to change the role using `setSortRole`, for index widgets the easiest thing to do is put some sorting hash value into the display role (note: this doesn't affect how the widget is shown in the view).

For this application here is a hash function:

```
    int sortKey()
    {
        int r, g, b, rgb;
        m_pen.color().getRgb(&r, &g, &b);
        rgb = (r * 65536) + (g * 256) + b;

        rgb *= styleModel->rowCount();
        rgb += m_pen.style();

        rgb *= widthModel->rowCount();
        rgb += m_pen.width();

        return rgb;
    }
```

Then when creating the index:

```
QStandardItem* penItem = new QStandardItem;
QPenWidget* pen = new QPenWidget;
tableView->setIndexWidget(penIndex, pen);
penItem->setData(pen->sortKey(), Qt::DisplayRole);
```